# How does Rails know to use "as_json" in a Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables

I'm reading this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast

Mid-way down the page, Ryan says

> The as_json method is triggered behind the scenes by the render_json
>   call in the controller.

but no more explanation is given. I'm trying to have this class respond with CSV as well, but `def as_csv` in the class and `format.csv { render :csv =>` in the calling controller does nothing.

So, somehow the class knows when it was initialized by `render :json`, but I can't figure out how to make it know it was initialized by `render :csv`. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an object to `render :json`, the `as_json` method is called on that object to retrieve a JSON representation of that object. You can overwrite this method so that it returns whatever you want.

This only works specifically for JSON, it's not a general rule that can be applied to all formats. If you'd like to render a CSV representation of some object, you can do it easily enough by using something like:

```
format.csv do
  render :text => object.as_csv
end
```

and then implementing the `as_csv` method in the class.

Comment: This works! Thanks. But, I still don't understand why it works for only JSON. I created an initializer to add a CSV Renderer to Rails's default renderers, the code is [here](http://pastebin.com/UqnCea9t), but that still didn't work. How could I add something to Rails so that this would work for things other than JSON?

Comment: Yes, that should work as well. Of course you need to use `to_csv` instead of `as_csv` with this code.

Comment: Ugh. I just noticed that. Well, that's what I get for copy and pasting code.